# What is the best way to load files from an expansion file in the NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I wrote a native android app which use openGL ES and APK expansion file because it's greater than 50MB.
All my textures are in the .obb file and I load this in java (with APKExpansionSupport).

Here is my method to load the image from the expansion

```
public static Bitmap getImageWithName(String a_path)
{
    Bitmap t_image = null;  
    try
    {
        InputStream t_inputStream = expansionFile.getInputStream(a_path);
        t_image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(t_inputStream);            
        t_inputStream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return t_image;
}
```

And here is my jni method to get the image :

```
BImage * WFileLoader::getImage(const BString& a_path, FileLocation a_location)
{
    ...

    jmethodID javaMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "getImageWithName","(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");

    if( javaMethod )
    {
        jobject t_bitmap = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(cls, javaMethod, t_path, t_location);

        if(t_bitmap)
        {
            jclass t_bitmapClass = env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap");

            jmethodID t_getWidthMethod = env->GetMethodID(t_bitmapClass, "getWidth", "()I");
            jmethodID t_getHeightMethod =env->GetMethodID(t_bitmapClass, "getHeight", "()I");

            jint t_width = env->CallIntMethod(t_bitmap,t_getWidthMethod);
            jint t_height = env->CallIntMethod(t_bitmap,t_getHeightMethod);

            jmethodID t_getPixelsMethod = env->GetMethodID(t_bitmapClass, "getPixels", "([IIIIIII)V");

            jintArray t_intBuffer = env->NewIntArray(t_width*t_height);
            jint t_offset = 0;
            jint t_stride = t_width;
            jint t_x = 0;
            jint t_y=0;

            env->CallVoidMethod(t_bitmap,t_getPixelsMethod,t_intBuffer,t_offset,t_stride,t_x,t_y,t_width,t_height);

        ....    
    }
}

... 
}
```

The texture loading is very long and takes about 30% of my CPU time (BitmapFactory.decodeStream takes the larger part). Does anybody has a better solution to load it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use zzip to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use mountObb() from the Android SDK to mount my APK file. It works fast and efficient for reading files stored in the APK.

```
// Get OBB path
mSM = (StorageManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
String tPackageName = "main." + versionCode + "." + getPackageName() + ".obb";
mObbPath = new File(Helpers.getSaveFilePath(this), tPackageName).getPath();

// Mount OBB
try {
    // We don't need to synchronize here to avoid clobbering the
    // content of mStatus because the callback comes to our main
    // looper.
    if (mSM.mountObb(mObbPath, null, mEventListener)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to mount OBB");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to start OBB mount.");
    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "OBB already mounted.");
}
```

Once it's mounted, you can access the files using the file path given by getMountedObbPath()

```
String tObbPath = mSM.getMountedObbPath(mObbPath)+ "/";
```

You will need to make a mountable obb file with your files inside its filesystem.

I use obbtool from the AOSP (have to clone and compile the repo in Linux) but recently I found jobb which seems to be able to do the job and is included in the Android SDK? (Untested)

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html